# Twitter4j: Exception in thread "Twitter4J Async Dispatcher[1]" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet

Tags: twitter4j

When i am trying to call the Twitter object in order to get the followers of a user, i got back the following exception: "Exception in thread "Twitter4J Async Dispatcher[1]" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet."
Do you have any idea, how to solve this issue?
Here is the related code part:

```
try {
        Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
        long lCursor = -1;
        IDs friendsIDs = twitter.getFriendsIDs(user.getId(), lCursor);
        do {
            System.out.println("in do while iteration");
            for (long i : friendsIDs.getIDs()) {
                System.out.println("Follower ID #" + i);
                System.out.println(twitter.showUser(i).getName());
            }
        } while (friendsIDs.hasNext());
    } catch (TwitterException te) {
        te.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Failed to get friends' ids: " + te.getMessage());
        System.exit(-1);
    }
```

Thanks a lot